# Error after updating core from 8.6.2 to 8.7.14

Tags: 8, updating

After I have updated my Drupal core version from 8.6.2 to 8.7.14, I have got below error at the time of cache clear and db update.

**Below error occurs while running update.php**

```
An AJAX HTTP error has occurred. HTTP result code: 200 Debug information follows. 
Path: /update.php/start?id=55&op=do_nojs&op=do 
Status text: OK 
Answer text: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager :: __ construct(), 
5 passed and exactly 6 expected in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->__construct()
(line 92 of C:\myproject\html\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php).
```

**This error occured at the time of cache rebuilt (Drush cr)**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager::
__construct(), 5 passed in C:\myproject\html\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php on line 285 
and exactly 6 expected in C:\myproject\html\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php:92
```

I didn't find any core patch or any other solution.
Any help?

Comment: Did you enabled any contrib or custom module after core update?

Comment: You could attempt to manually delete all `cache_[something]` tables in the database. That should force Drupal into re-indexing all services. Then try updating again.

Comment: No, not enabled anything @JuyalJee

Comment: cleared all cache & watchdog tables, but no luck. It seems there is some core file issue @Neograph734.